# Jquery AJAX posting variable to server file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

Using Jquery AJAX to read a number from a server file, increment the number, and write the number back to the server file.

I can read the file fine, I just can't post to the file.

```
<script>
var counter = -1;

$.ajax({
    type:    "GET",
    url:     "counter.txt",
    success: function(text) {
    counter = text;
    counter++;
        $("#count").html(counter);
    },
    error:   function() {
        $("#count").html("Error!");
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type:    "POST",
    url:     "counter.txt",
    data:    counter,
    success: function() {
    },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax being a client-side method can't write to a file on the server.

You would need some middleware in PHP, ASP, Python etc to take the amends as posted data and write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ajax is asynchronous, this piece of code

```
$.ajax({
    type:    "POST",
    url:     "counter.txt",
    data:    counter,
    success: function() {
    },
});
```

will be executed before you will get first number from server. You need to put this code inside "success" function

```
$.ajax(
    type:    "GET",
    url:     "counter.txt",
    success: function(text) {
        counter = text;
        counter++;
        $("#count").html(counter);
        $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
            url:     "counter.txt",
            data:    counter,
            success: function() {
            },
        });
    },
    error:   function() {
        $("#count").html("Error!");
    }
});
```

Also, you should just call some server side php method through Ajax, since you can't set anything through JavaScript on server.
So "post" Ajax URL should looks like 
url: 'http://www.server.ca/set_vars?var=var_title&value=' + encodeURIcomponent(counter)

Comment: Sergey, this is a nice answer... but you need to format you code correctly. Please put 4 spaces before each line with code on it.